# UICollectionView imageview animation

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm fairly new to swift/objective C and I'm wondering if anyone can help me with a problem i've been having relating to image view animation (scroll from right to left). I currently have an UIImageView on my VC and it animates through no problem. However, I think it may be best if I used a UICollectionView instead. Could anyone please kindly point me in the right direction in doing this, please? I have yet to deal with collection view into depth so the concept is relatively new to me. My code for the current situation is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var sponsorAnimation: UIImageView!
let images = [
    UIImage(named: "runforcure")!,
    UIImage(named: "marquee")!]

var index = 0

let animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1
let switchingInterval: NSTimeInterval = 3

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sponsorAnimation.image = images[index]
    animateImageView()

}

func animateImageView() {
    CATransaction.begin()

    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(animationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(self.switchingInterval * NSTimeInterval(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.animateImageView()
        }
    }

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    /*
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    */
    sponsorAnimation.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    sponsorAnimation.image = images[index]

    CATransaction.commit()

    index = index < images.count - 1 ? index + 1 : 0

}
```

My ideal situation would be a single image showing at a time, and it'll scroll from right to left every 3 seconds.

UPDATE: I think I'm really close, however in the last two line of codes i don't know where to place the self.collectionview? . Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance once again!

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let images = [UIImage(named: "oneteam"), UIImage(named: "runforcure")]

var timer = NSTimer()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("switchImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.images.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView?.image = self.images[indexPath.row]


    /*I don't know where to place this line of code? If I place is outside of this function then it says unresolved identifier 'indexPath'*/
    self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)

    return cell

}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: currently in my switchImage() function, the indexPath isn't registering in the system...I'm definitely missing something!

Answer (score 0):

You can put a CollectionView on your view controller and make a customized collection view cell that is the size of the collection view (so only one cell fits on the screen at a time) and contains an image view.

This will allow users to swipe through the images with a nice snap animation between cells as well as you can easily animate through the collectionview index of cells on a timer with the method:

ObjC:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];
```

Swift:

```
self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

Setting up a collection view and custom cell tutorial: http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: silly question but I apply the self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(...) within a collection view function correct?

Comment: Silly questions are the best! -- You could call the self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath in any method within the view controller that you have a reference to 'self.collectionView?' (otherwise self.collectionView wont exist and your app will be consfused);; So for instance, in your viewDidLoad method of the view controller that containts yoru collectionview you can start a NSTimer which calls a method on itself:  switchImage(){ self.collectionView?.scrollToItem.. } at an interval of time.

Comment: timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target:self, selector: Selector("switchImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: BOOL)

Comment: Hi Josh, I must be missing something as I currently run into errors. Please see attached code in my edited question! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() timer=NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5,target: self, selector: Selector("switchImage"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true) }` i get an error saying unresolved identifier 'timer'? Where do I declare this timer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate actions here.

First, you need to populate the collection view with data. That is what you're doing in *cellForItemAtIndexPath*.

Second you need to animate through you collection view that was just populated with data (your images).

If you want it to be fullscreen, just set each cell size to the bounds of the collection view.

In viewDidLoad be sure to have your data source for the collection view setup and the data ready.

After that you can set a timer to start scrolling through the index paths. You'll need to build your own NSIndexPath objects. You just need to keep track on the photo array index (as the row) if there is only one section.

Finally, you'll need a condition to know when you're at the end of the photos to stop the timer (row < images.count).

Comment: Could you please clarify how I would go about building my own NSIndexPath objects?

Comment: okay so I just tried declaring in my ViewController Class `var indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, forSection: 0)` ... am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes. You will ignore the section (it will always be 0) and then just increment the row, which is your photo array index.

I would create a helper method to wrap your index (NSUInteger) in a NSIndexPath for the collection view to use.

    - (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForPhotoIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index section:0];
    }